# How to plot elements of arrays in a timeplot, showing one value from each every 5 seconds

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to show the results of a tensorflow model onto a timeplot. I have two arrays, one for the predictions of the model and one for the actual values. Both arrays are of the size (3500,) with values ranging from 0-16. I want to be able to show a timeplot that displays the predicted value and the actual value at a certain point in time. I do not know how to setup a timeplot that has the values on the y-axis and time on the x-axis.

I am currently using the Matplotlib library to make this work but I am not too familiar with it

```
plt.scatter(max_test,max_predictions)
plt.show()
```

This gives me a scatter plot with the values (0-16) on both the y and x-axis.
[image]
I want to replace the values on the x-axis with the time that each value occurred at (preferably every 5 seconds) and only show one value for both the arrays. Ideally it would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: could you use a for loop with sleep(5) then plot and show the graph? (note you would use `plt.show(block=False)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the start time and stop time, you can import numpy and use linspace for the x axis:

```
x_axis_val = np.linspace(start, stop, len(max_test))
```

To plot both sets of y-values on the same graph do:

```
plots = [max_predictions, max_test]
for plot in plots:
    plt.scatter(x_axis_val,plot)
plt.show()
```